# I want to test with Selenium, but I get an error Webdrivers :: BrowserNotFound

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I currently write tests using Rails5, Rspec, Selenium, and webdrivers gems.
However, I get the error Webdrivers :: BrowserNotFound and I can't run it.

I think this is due to Selenium not finding a ChromeDriver.
However, this problem should have been solved by a webdrivers gem, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.
Details will be written below.

- Error Log

```
     1.1) Failure/Error: visit hoges_index_path

          Webdrivers::BrowserNotFound:
            Failed to find Chrome binary.



          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webdrivers-4.1.2/lib/webdrivers/chrome_finder.rb:21:in `location'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webdrivers-4.1.2/lib/webdrivers/chrome_finder.rb:10:in `version'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webdrivers-4.1.2/lib/webdrivers/chromedriver.rb:46:in `browser_version'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webdrivers-4.1.2/lib/webdrivers/chromedriver.rb:106:in `release_version'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webdrivers-4.1.2/lib/webdrivers/chromedriver.rb:32:in `latest_version'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webdrivers-4.1.2/lib/webdrivers/common.rb:136:in `correct_binary?'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webdrivers-4.1.2/lib/webdrivers/common.rb:92:in `update'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/webdrivers-4.1.2/lib/webdrivers/chromedriver.rb:119:in `block in <top (required)>'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:133:in `binary_path'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:94:in `initialize'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:41:in `new'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:41:in `chrome'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:299:in `service_url'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/driver.rb:40:in `initialize'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:46:in `new'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:46:in `for'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.3/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:88:in `for'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-3.28.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:49:in `browser'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-3.28.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:68:in `visit'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-3.28.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:276:in `visit'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-3.28.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
          # ./spec/views/hoge/index_spec.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

- TestCode

```rb
RSpec.feature 'HogeIndex', type: :system do
  before(:each) do
    visit hoges_index_path
  end
  scenario 'hoge' do
    expect(all('.hoge').count).to eq 1
  end
end
```

- rails_helper.rb

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ~~~
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome_headless do |app|
    browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    browser_options.args << '--headless'
    browser_options.args << '--no-sandbox'
    browser_options.args << '--disable-gpu'
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options)
  end

  config.before(:each) do |example|
    if example.metadata[:type] == :system
      driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless, screen_size: [700, 700]
    end
  end
  ~~~~
end
```

I also turned on Webdrivers Debug logging.
Here is the log at that time.

```
2019-10-19 02:12:03 DEBUG Webdrivers Checking current version
2019-10-19 02:12:03 DEBUG Webdrivers /root/.webdrivers/chromedriver is not already downloaded
2019-10-19 02:12:04 DEBUG Webdrivers Checking current version
2019-10-19 02:12:04 DEBUG Webdrivers /root/.webdrivers/chromedriver is not already downloaded
F2019-10-19 02:12:10 DEBUG Webdrivers Checking current version
2019-10-19 02:12:10 DEBUG Webdrivers /root/.webdrivers/chromedriver is not already downloaded
2019-10-19 02:12:11 DEBUG Webdrivers Checking current version
2019-10-19 02:12:11 DEBUG Webdrivers /root/.webdrivers/chromedriver is not already downloaded
F2019-10-19 02:12:17 DEBUG Webdrivers Checking current version
2019-10-19 02:12:17 DEBUG Webdrivers /root/.webdrivers/chromedriver is not already downloaded
2019-10-19 02:12:18 DEBUG Webdrivers Checking current version
2019-10-19 02:12:18 DEBUG Webdrivers /root/.webdrivers/chromedriver is not already downloaded
F2019-10-19 02:12:25 DEBUG Webdrivers Checking current version
2019-10-19 02:12:25 DEBUG Webdrivers /root/.webdrivers/chromedriver is not already downloaded
2019-10-19 02:12:26 DEBUG Webdrivers Checking current version
2019-10-19 02:12:26 DEBUG Webdrivers /root/.webdrivers/chromedriver is not already downloaded
F
```

I will wait for your reply.

Comment: can you provide the full file or at least show where you are requiring the webdriver gems and which ones?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm sorry for the lack of information.
The place where you need webdrivers is the code that starts the browser through selenium?
I wrote a part of my test code. please look.

Answer (score 4):

It is solved.
It was because Google Chrome was not installed.
I'm sorry.

Comment: Only this solution works for me on macbook pro. Thanks.

Comment: Don't be sorry!  I had the same problem! :-)